# finding equation of ragged suface or non geometric curve

Tags: calculus

I am amateur in mathematics . I have done research regarding this question . I was not able to find any answers .

I want to know the techniques used to find equation to represent  a ragged surface . For example how do they find equation to represent curve on human face in 3D .

In the fallowing picture the their is 2 value of f(x) at x . Mathematical function does not behave in this way . How can a equation be written for this

[image]

Comment: Since $y=f(x)$ is no good, you need a parametric curve: $x=u(t), y=v(t)$.

Comment: As  Ivan Neretin commented, parametric splines work very well for any number of dimensions.

Comment: thanks @IvanNeretin  .  I have to go back to school and learn things